# Execute code on nodejs server shutdown with express

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to execute a piece of code in Node.js Express just before the node.js process exits, regardless whether it was due to an error being thrown, or pressing Ctrl+C, or any other reason?

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for the exit event. From the documentation:

> Emitted when the process is about to exit. This is a good hook to
>   perform constant time checks of the module's state (like for unit
>   tests). The main event loop will no longer be run after the 'exit'
>   callback finishes, so timers may not be scheduled.

And it would be implemented as

```
process.on('exit', function() {
    console.log('About to close');
});
```

It's worth mentioning, that it's generally not a good idea to try to manipulate data if you don't know the reason for the exit or exception. If you don't know what's wrong, it's usually a better idea to start fresh, than try to accomplish something with something that may very well be FUBAR.

Comment: f@#$ed up beyond all recognition/repair/reason.

Comment: I managed to acheive what I want with: process.on('SIGINT', function() {.

Comment: I made with process.on('SIGTERM'